# Ecto constraint error when attempting to delete struct

Tags: database, postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `User` model that `has_many` Medical Informations, and Medical Informations `belongs_to` User.

When i try to delete a `User` that has associated records (medical informations), `Ecto` gives me the following error:

```
 ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to delete struct:

     * foreign_key: medical_informations_user_id_fkey

 If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
 call foreign_key_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
 constraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.
```

I tried to add `foreign_key_constraint/3` to my default changeset in both models but the error continues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ecto has a constraint to check if an entry can be deleted if doesn't have records associated `Ecto.Changeset.no_assoc_constraint/3`. With this validation i get a nice error that i can use like this `associated_records are still associated to this entry`.

Another useful constraint is `Ecto.Changeset.foreign_key_constraint/3`, that is useful to guarantee that a child will only be created if the parent exists in the database too.

Comment: This link for others with this problem: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html